# Can I eliminate a switch controlled receptacle, and use the switch to control a ceiling fan instead?

Tags: electrical, ceiling-fan

I'm planning on installing a new ceiling fan and was hoping to have a few questions answered before I dive into things. First some context:

The existing wall switch controls half of the outlet on the other side of the room. I'd like to convert this outlet to be always hot and use a dual switch for the fan something like this:

[image: Double switch]

I opened up the outlets and this is what it looks like (I forgot to take a picture of the inside of the box, I can do that if it helps):

[image: Old receptacle]
[image: Old switch]

And this is what the switch looks like:

[image: Old switch]
[image: Wires]

I crawled in the attic and it looks like the 12/3 romex from the switch to the outlet runs through there.

In order to set this up right, can I cut that romex line in the attic and attach it to a box for the ceiling fan? And then pull the excess line that is attached to the outlet and discard it?

In order to convert the outlet to be always hot, do I need to buy a new one? I'm assuming there isn't a way to replace the tab?

Comment: Would you be adding a light kit to the ceiling fan? Is there already a switch controlled lighting fixture in the room?

Comment: The fan has a light kit on it, so yes...and no the switch does not control a light. Only the outlet.  It looks like the romex from the switch to the outlet runs up and through the crawlspace.

Comment: What I'm getting at, is that there's a requirement that all rooms have at least one switch controlled light.  Often this requirement is meet by plugging a lamp into a switch controlled receptacle.

Comment: I see, yes, I would still be satisfying that requirement